# Stargazer mudando a posição da variavel dependente

Tags: r, latex, regressão

Considerando as regressões quantílicas.

```
library(quantreg)

> x=rnorm(100,12,2)
> y=rnorm(100,0,4)

a<-rq(y~x,tau = .10)
b<-rq(y~x,tau = .15)
c<-rq(y~x,tau = .20)
d<-rq(y~x,tau = .25)
```

Como eu só tenho uma constante e uma variável explicativa eu gostaria de colocar como colunas X e a constante, ou seja, "transpor" o resultado que o pacote `stargazer` me oferece, que é o oposto desse aqui:

```
stargazer(a,b,c,d,title="Regression Results",align=TRUE, dep.var.caption="",model.numbers=TRUE,intercept.bottom=FALSE,font.size="scriptsize",keep.stat="aic",dep.var.labels="",multicolumn=TRUE,ci=TRUE,ci.level=0.90,dep.var.labels.include=TRUE)
```

O `stargazer` gera uma tabela assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero é que cada `tau` esteja nas linhas, tendo, assim, uma tabela com `tau´s` linhas e 2 colunas.

Há como?

Comment: Olá Diogo. Dica importante pra facilitar que você tenha ajuda mais rapidamente/facilmente: construa e disponibilize um [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Difícil deixatr tão completa quanto a tabela produzida pelo `stargazer`, se você puder simplificá-la, pode fazer assim:

```
modelos <- list(a,b,c,d)
param <- plyr::ldply(modelos, function(x) coef(x))
param <- cbind(data.frame(tau = seq(0.1, 0.25, by = 0.05)),
               param)

xtable::xtable(param)
```

Ele produzirá o seguinte `Latex`

```
% latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Mon May 23 15:34:54 2016
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  \hline
 & tau & (Intercept) & x \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0.10 & -12.75 & 0.61 \\ 
  2 & 0.15 & -9.13 & 0.41 \\ 
  3 & 0.20 & -7.15 & 0.29 \\ 
  4 & 0.25 & -5.52 & 0.19 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Que compilado dá essa tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembre-se de ter instalado os pacotes `plyr` e `xtable`, usando `install.packages("nome_do_pacote")`.

O `xtable` possui diversas opções de configuração da tabela, você pode dar uma olhada neste [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf) para saber mais.